# Project builds and deploys sucessfully - But unable to start

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I can successfully build my BizTalk project and deploy it on my local machine.

However, when I start the application in the  BizTalk Admin Console it complains that it:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'XXXXX, Version=X.X.X.X, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxx' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. (Microsoft.BizTalk.ExplorerOM)
```

If it builds successfully how can it be complaining about a dll it cant find?

Any thoughts are much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dlls need be signed and added to GAC.
My guess is some dlls your application depends is not added to GAC.